# Parsing RSS feed and Storing in database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have developed andriod news app by using rss feeds parsing. I have around 20 different rss feeds. I want to download the rss feeds as user connects to internet and update in database so that when user open a app he sees updated connect what is best achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a background [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to process downloading the feeds time-to-time and saving to a local data base.

Your activity will fetch data from this local data base and may trigger the service for updates.